# tensorflow 2, using tensor as index without for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

Let's say I have a tensor of shape `[3000,20,10],` I'll call it `input`... I have another tensor of shape [3000] that contains only indices for the 3rd dimension of the first tensor, I'll call it "indices"

Basically, for every `i` in `0:2999`, I want `input[i,20,indices[i]]...` So my final output will be of shape `[3000,20]`

I should be able to easily do this with a for loop, but I would like to find how to do this without a for loop... I tried looking at `tf.gather` but was honestly too confused to have any success in that direction

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Activation, Add, MaxPooling2D, LSTM, Dense
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.range(3000*20*10)
input = tf.reshape(input, (3000,20,10))
indices = tf.random.uniform((3000,), 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)
inds = indices[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
inds = tf.repeat(inds, 20, 1)
output = tf.gather(input, inds, batch_dims=2, axis=2)
output = tf.squeeze(output)
import random
for _ in range(100):
  i = random.randint(0, 2999)
  j = random.randint(0, 19)
  print(input[i][j][[indices[i]]]==output[i][j])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems your code takes the output and repeats it 20 times to account for the 2nd dimension.

However, I don't want the output repeating 20 times, it's 20 different values.  Does that make sense?

In other words, your code takes input[i,0,j] and repeats it 20 times, but I need to have input[i,0:19,j] instead.

Comment: @KaziTanzeemShahid please see the edited answer